# How can I test my radio module without software to be sure it is not physically broken

Tags: rf, raspberry-pi, radio, testing, lora

I have recently bought a `modtronix InAir9` radio module that I use with a `Raspberry PI Zero W` to play with the LoRa network.

I followed multiple tutorials with different software to try to make it work on the raspberry but without any success. Everytime it is like the module is not connected to the board. I have checked and rechecked (and even made it checked by someone else) that everything is properly connected where it should be.

Now I am starting to think the radio module might be damaged but I can't be sure, it might just be me not using the software properly (but I don't think so since it is pretty straight forward). Is there any way I can test my radio module to check if it is damaged without a software running on my raspberry? And if so, what would I need?

Here is some links to the module and tutorials:

[InAir9 radio Module](http://modtronix.com/inair9.html)

[pySX127x library with test and tutorial](https://github.com/mayeranalytics/pySX127x)

[loragateway library with step by step turotial and schema](https://github.com/CongducPham/tutorials/blob/master/Low-cost-LoRa-GW-step-by-step.pdf)

Comment: Have you tried a manual reset once powered up?

Comment: Sorry but I don't get what you mean, could you explain?

Comment: There is a reset pin on the device according to the site you linked - maybe it needs a reset after powering up. Or maybe there is a short that is holding the device in a state of reset. Do you have a multimeter to check voltages?

Comment: Ah yes, but I am guessing the software should take care of the reset if it is needed right? If not, how can I produce the reset myself? And no, I don't have a multimeter right now, but I should have one soon, what would I check exactly with it?

Comment: I would suggest contacting the manufacturer. If it is some user error such as a reset on powerup, it is likely they have come across this before. They might also have other suggestions to try. In general, it is easiest to narrow down this problem by slowly eliminating parts - Can you try the device on another raspberry, can you use another radio module with your raspberry, do the ports you use on your raspberry work when connecting to other digital devices, ...

Comment: Yes, I see what you mean and I already did a bit of that, the raspberry seems to be fine though, I tested it with some LED and sadly I don't have an other radio module. I might try to contact the manufacturer like you said. But is there any other way I could test the module to see if it is damaged?

Comment: How are you "talking" to the module with the Pi (via SPI)? You could toggle an LED on the Pi when getting a response from the module to see if your communication is working...

Comment: That is an interesting idea, but wouldn't I need to modify the software for that? Or can I just enable something elsewhere to toggle the LED?